# Default values for Query Parameter in Vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

```
Versions:
Vert.x core: 3.8.3
vert.x web: 3.8.3
```

I am trying to feed default value for Query Params, but I am not getting any API for that.

for Example:
We have this type of APIs

```
 private void data(RoutingContext routingContext) {
String spotname = routingContext.request().getParam("threshold");
}
```

but in this case, we can not set default values,
can we get like this or is any way to achieve this using vertx:

```
 private void data(RoutingContext routingContext) {
String threshold = routingContext.request().getParam("threshold", "0.76");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own method for that:

```
private void data(RoutingContext ctx) {
 String threshold = getParam(ctx,"threshold","0.76");
}

public static String getParam(RoutingContext ctx, String paramName, String defaultValue) {
    String param = ctx.request().getParam(paramName);
    return param == null ? defaultValue : param;
}
```

Comment: YES, same I have written but I was searching native support by Vert.x as Jersey project has.

Comment: you can create a pull request, there is no native support for this now.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to create pull request in the upcoming weekend.